# display icons and text in one line with same gap between each

Tags: html, css

please visit [here](http://stylebaby.com/cases-covers/art-graphics.html) ,  on top right 3 icons and text is displaying

[image]

i want to hide gap b/w 1st & 2nd icon , also i want to display text : `indian rupees` after 3rd icon.

```css
float: right;
position: relative;
top: 29px;
z-index: 999;
```

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code real fast, the alignment of the icons is a wee bit off. For a cleaner simpler solution, using pseudo code below, you simply do something like this

```
<div id="topRightWrapper">
   <div class="miniIcons">search icon here</div>
   <div class="miniIcons">cart button here</div>
   <div class="miniIcons">person icon here</div>
   <div class="miniIcons">Currency text here</div>
</div>
```

and then you simply "float right"  the "topRightWrapper", and float left/right the "miniIcons".

Then, you may have to adjust a bit the popup functionality you get with those buttons but not by much.

PS: Looking further @ your code, you are almost there but the problem is that the currency text/div, isnt in the same parent wrapper as the other icons. If you place them in the same manner i said above, it will work. You COULD technically do it with absolute positioning etc but thats a nightmare for something this simple. Hope this helps.